# ComboBoxItem Selection Area Issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a comboBox with a ComboBox.ItemTemplate

```
<ComboBox>
   <ComboxBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel}">
         <TextBlock Text="1" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboxBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The Item renders properly, but when I try to select the ComboxItem, the selection is only available on "1" rest of the Area in the ComboBoxItem is not clickable.

How do I set up the code so the selection can happen on the whole item and not just the Textblock.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this the full ComboBox definition? I'm very sure that this isn't the usual behavior

Comment: I can't duplicate this in .NET 3.5. When using the data template you provided, I can select the entire combobox item. However, if I surround the textbox with a ComboBoxItem, I can see something similar to what you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ComboBox/ComboBoxItem seems to be templated, by default the highlight brush is a deeper blue. If you have access to the templates make sure the content of the ComboBoxItem stretches horizontally.

If the template is bound "correctly" setting the content-alignments may be enough.

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Should looked at the simplest solution first.